# Como sobrepor flex itens durante um hover em CSS?

Tags: css, css-hover

Tenho um formulário que recebeu `display: flex`, e dentro dele tem 3 `inputs`: um de nome, um de senha e um botão, além de um `h1` escrito 'login'.

Quando passo o mouse sobre os elementos, o `height` e o `width` aumentam, só que o elemento de cima do elemento que aumenta não fica parado, ele vai para cima.

Queria saber se tem algum comando que eu possa usar para ele permitir a sobreposição das margens e não ir pra cima.

Código:

```css
*{color: white}

body{
    background: rgb(1, 1, 24);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: white;
}

.formulario{
    display: flex;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px 1px rgb(29, 172, 0)
}

.login{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 60px;
}

.nome{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    border:solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.nome:hover, .nome:focus{
    border: solid 3px rgb(29, 172, 0);
    padding: 7px 50px;
    transition: ease-in-out 70ms;
}

.nome::placeholder{
    font-family: cursive; 
    text-align: center;
}

.senha{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    border:solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.senha:hover, .senha:focus{
    border: solid 3px  rgb(29, 172, 0);
    padding: 7px 50px;
    transition: ease-in-out 70ms;
}

.senha::placeholder{
    font-family: cursive; 
    text-align: center;
}

.enviar{
    background:rgb(29, 172, 0);
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: solid 1px rgb(29, 172, 0);
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    color: black;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: bold
}

.enviar:hover{
    padding: 20px 36px;
    transition: ease-in-out 70ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Formulário estilizado 01</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" class="formulario">
     <h1 class="login">LOGIN</h1>
     <input type="text" class="nome" placeholder="nome">
     <input type="password" class="senha" placeholder="senha">
     <input type="submit" value="enviar" class="enviar">

    </form>
    
    <script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo só o seu relato não ajuda muito a te responder, só no chute! Por favor edite sua pergunta e inclua o CSS e o HTML desse form etc

Comment: obg, amigo. já editei e coloquei meu código css, pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque cada elemento do formulário dentro de uma div flex com uma altura fixa. No exemplo abaixo coloquei `55px` de `height`. Se quiser também pode criar uma classe para cada div para ajustar o espaçamento entre um elemento e outro:

```css
*{
   color: white;
   position: relative;
   }

body{
    background: rgb(1, 1, 24);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: white;
}

.formulario{
    display: flex;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px 1px rgb(29, 172, 0)
}

/* estilos das divs */
.formulario div{
   height: 55px;
   display: flex;
   position: relative;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}


.login{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 60px;
}

.nome{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    border:solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.nome:hover, .nome:focus{
    border: solid 3px rgb(29, 172, 0);
    padding: 7px 50px;
    transition: ease-in-out 70ms;
}

.nome::placeholder{
    font-family: cursive; 
    text-align: center;
}

.senha{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    border:solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.senha:hover, .senha:focus{
    border: solid 3px  rgb(29, 172, 0);
    padding: 7px 50px;
    transition: ease-in-out 70ms;
}

.senha::placeholder{
    font-family: cursive; 
    text-align: center;
}

.enviar{
    background:rgb(29, 172, 0);
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: solid 1px rgb(29, 172, 0);
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    color: black;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: bold
}

.enviar:hover{
    padding: 20px 36px;
    transition: ease-in-out 70ms;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" class="formulario">
   <h1 class="login">LOGIN</h1>
   <div>
      <input type="text" class="nome" placeholder="nome">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="password" class="senha" placeholder="senha">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="submit" value="enviar" class="enviar">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: valeu maninho, seu código foi o que mais me ajudou <3

Answer (score 3):

Apesar do código não ter ficado muito bonito pq fiz na correria acho que pode te ajudar.

A ideia aqui é envolver o `input` em uma `label`, por questão de semântica, e tb para poder  usar um pseudo elemento na `label`, já que não é possível aplicar diretamente no `input` um pseudo elemento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse pseudo elemento `::after` é que eu vou aplicar esse efeito que vc quer, no caso eu usei `transform:scale()` apenas para agilizar, mas vc pode usar valores em `heigth` e `width` nele se preferir. Assim vc vai aplicar os efeito no `::after` do `label`, e não diretamente no `input`.

Segue o modelo. Sugiro que de uma analisada no código, pois como falei ele pode andar ser melhorado, fiz esse modelo apenas para te explicar o conceito...

```css
*{color: white}

body{
    background: rgb(1, 1, 24);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: white;
}

.formulario{
    display: flex;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 0px 1px rgb(29, 172, 0);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.login{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 60px;
}


label:last-child {
    color: black;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
label:last-child::after {
    background:rgb(29, 172, 0);
    border: solid 1px rgb(29, 172, 0);
    padding: 6px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  transform: scale(1) translateX(calc(50% - -3px));
}

label:last-child:hover::after{
  transform: scale(1.2) translateX(calc(50% - 7.5px));
  top: -9px;
  /* left: 0; */
  transition: all ease-in-out 70ms;
}

input {
  all: unset;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
label {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  border:solid 1px white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
label:hover::after {
  border: solid 3px rgb(29, 172, 0);
  transform: scale(1.6, 1.2);
  top: -3px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 70ms;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" class="formulario">
  <h1 class="login">LOGIN</h1>
  <label><input type="text" class="nome" placeholder="nome"></label>
  <label><input type="password" class="senha" placeholder="senha"></label>
  <label><input type="submit" value="enviar" class="enviar"></label>
</form>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, agora eu entendi a lógica do código <3